# Sort/group array by key

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, sorting, ksort

**TL;DR**

Sort/group array by key without adding another level to the array (data parsed by jQuery plugin)?

**Details**

I am building an array to return to some `<select>` DOM element.

It takes in CC (engine size stuff) as a parameter and uses that as a key, the problem lies with sorting the array after.

Let's say, user selects this range of CC's:

> 50, 100, 125
>
> 50 has 32 options available
>
> 100 has 3 options available
>
> 125 has 12 options available

My current code loops through the CC's, executes the SQL to get the options and using a loop counter creates the key like this:

```
$options[$cc. $id] = $someValue;
```

This works as you'd expect, however my output is showing results not in exactly the order I need (`CC ASC` - so all 50s should show first, together).

The problem is that

> 50 with 32 goes upto `5031` as a key.
>   100 with 3 goes upto `1002` as a key.
>   125 with 12 goes upto `12511` as a key.

By now hopefully you can clearly see the issue. 5031 is greater than 1002. So options for 50cc with a loop counter passed 9 is greater than 100cc options.

(just for clarity, example output is):

> 50cc Option 1 
>   50cc Option 2 
>   50cc Option 3 
>   50cc Option 4 
>   50cc Option 5 
>   100cc Option 1 
>   100cc Option 2 
>  
>   100cc Option 3 
>   50cc Option 6 
>   50cc Option 7

Maybe the initial problem is how I'm creating the keys, but I've tried to use `ksort` with a few different flags to try and achieve my goal but none of the flags seem to target what I'm after:

> ```
> SORT_REGULAR - compare items normally (don't change types)
> SORT_NUMERIC - compare items numerically
> SORT_STRING - compare items as strings
> SORT_LOCALE_STRING - compare items as strings, based on the current locale. It uses the locale, which can be changed using setlocale()
> SORT_NATURAL - compare items as strings using "natural ordering" like natsort()
> SORT_FLAG_CASE - can be combined (bitwise OR) with SORT_STRING or SORT_NATURAL to sort strings case-insensitively
> ```

How do I sort/group my keys without adding another level to my array (the data is parsed by a jQuery plugin that needs the data in a certain format)?

EDIT: Full Script

```
<?php
    if (strpos(PHP_OS, 'Linux') > -1) {
        require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. '/app/connect.php';
    } else {
        require_once getcwd(). '\\..\\..\\..\\..\\app\\connect.php';
    }

    $make = $_POST['make'];
    $cc = $_POST['cc'];

    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM `table`
                WHERE `UKM_CCM` = :cc
                AND `UKM_Make` = :make 
                ORDER BY `UKM_Model`, `UKM_StreetName`, `Year` ASC;';

    $options = array();

    foreach ($cc as $k => $value)
    {
        $res = $handler->prepare($sql);
        $res->execute(array(':cc' => $value, ':make' => $make));

        $data = $res->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        $i = 0;

        if (count($data) > 0) {
            foreach ($data as $result)
            {
                $arrayKey = sprintf('%03d%02d', $cc, $i);

                $epid = $result['ePID'];
                $make = $result['UKM_Make'];
                $model = $result['UKM_Model'];
                $cc = $result['UKM_CCM'];
                $year = $result['Year'];
                $sub = $result['UKM_Submodel'];
                $street = $result['UKM_StreetName'];

                $options[$arrayKey]['name'] = $make. ' ' .$model. ' ' .$cc. ' ' .$year. ' ' .$sub. ' ' .$street;
                $options[$arrayKey]['value'] = $epid;
                $options[$arrayKey]['checked'] = false;

                $options[$arrayKey]['attributes']['data-epid'] = $epid;
                $options[$arrayKey]['attributes']['data-make'] = $make;
                $options[$arrayKey]['attributes']['data-model'] = $model;
                $options[$arrayKey]['attributes']['data-cc'] = $cc;
                $options[$arrayKey]['attributes']['data-year'] = $year;
                $options[$arrayKey]['attributes']['data-sub'] = $sub;
                $options[$arrayKey]['attributes']['data-street'] = $street;

                $i++;
            }
        }
    }

    ksort($options, SORT_STRING);

    echo json_encode($options);
```

Comment: Can you order them in your SQL query?

Comment: @MickaelLeger they're separate SQL executions so no ... though now that you mention it, maybe I could change my SQL to use `WHERE IN ($values)` - gimme a momento! :)

Comment: Can you have a non-numeric key? I.e. "50.3"?

Comment: @AlexanderDeSousa it's a nice idea - but the JSON side doesn't seem to allow 'value.counter' - it returns 'value.' as a key :/ but nice thinking :) I'll try with _ or something :)

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs no problem, I have a written solution using uksort, as long as long as your key is able to have some sort of delimeter then I can do it.

Answer (score 2):

You could format the key to have 3 digits for the cc and 2 for the option...

```
$options[sprintf('%03d%02d', $cc, $id)] = $someValue;
```

which should give you keys `05031` and `10002`.

Then use `SORT_STRING` to force it to sort them as strings (although they would sort as numbers as well)

Comment: In theory this looked good but for whatever reason, it's not gone 125cc option X, 100cc options, some 50cc options, more 125s etc. :S

Comment: Can you add more of the code to your question (including SQL) which may help to understand it a bit more.

Comment: Have you checked what the `echo json_encode($options);` gives, can you add that (sorry have to go out, will be a few hours)

Comment: not with your code truth be told, with my original code I did - will see what it gives me :)

Answer (score 0):

If you can add the key additional into your array, you could create a `usort()` that will sort your array as you need it:

```
$arrSort = [50, 100, 125];
$arrData = [
    501 => [
        'foo',
        'bar',
        'arrayKey' => 501
    ],
    504 => [
        'foo',
        'bar',
        'arrayKey' => 504
    ],
    1002 => [
        'foo',
        'bar',
        'arrayKey' => 1002
    ],
    10045 => [
        'foo',
        'bar',
        'arrayKey' => 10045
    ],
    1251 => [
        'foo',
        'bar',
        'arrayKey' => 1251
    ],
    5045 => [
        'foo',
        'bar',
        'arrayKey' => 5045
    ]
];

usort($arrData, function($a, $b) use ($arrSort)
{
    $posA = array_search(substr($a['arrayKey'], 0, 2), $arrSort);
    if ($posA === false) {
        $posA = array_search(substr($a['arrayKey'], 0, 3), $arrSort);
    }

    $posB = array_search(substr($b['arrayKey'], 0, 2), $arrSort);
    if ($posB === false) {
        $posB = array_search(substr($b['arrayKey'], 0, 3), $arrSort);
    }

    return $posA - $posB;
});
```

The return of this function in this example would be:

> array:6 [▼   0 => array:3 [▼
>       0 => "foo"
>       1 => "bar"
>       "arrayKey" => 501   ]   1 => array:3 [▼
>       0 => "foo"
>       1 => "bar"
>       "arrayKey" => 504   ]   2 => array:3 [▼
>       0 => "foo"
>       1 => "bar"
>       "arrayKey" => 5045   ]   3 => array:3 [▼
>       0 => "foo"
>       1 => "bar"
>       "arrayKey" => 1002   ]   4 => array:3 [▼
>       0 => "foo"
>       1 => "bar"
>       "arrayKey" => 10045   ]   5 => array:3 [▼
>       0 => "foo"
>       1 => "bar"
>       "arrayKey" => 1251   ] ]

Comment: I tried above, sorts in the right numeric sense (e.g. 100, 125 are showing first, but 50 is last :S)

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs For me it was displayed as in the answer, with the 50 first. What PHP version are you running? Seems rather odd to me. Did you just run my code or did you integrate it in yours already?

Comment: PHP7.2 :) and integrate into my code - however, I think the plugin itself may be causing some issues .. I may try to do outside of the plugin and see if the result stays the same

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs The version is the same as mine. Maybe you could just copy & paste my code into an empty file in your project just as test and proof of concept to see if the issue lies within the code or your plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Make your 'faux delimiter' an uncommon pattern like "929292" in this example. Then you can use uksort to go through just your keys. replace "929292" with "." so you end up with something like "100.3", "125.12" and "150.32".

Now you're no longer limited to trying to work numerically and with patterns, you can use a good old explode and compare manually.

This solution doesn't care what's nested in your arrays, it's only concerned with the keys for sorting.

```
$options = [
  '1009292923' => '100cc',
  '12592929212' => '150cc',
  '5092929232' => '50cc'
];

$sorted = uksort($options, function($a, $b){
  $parts = explode('.',str_replace('929292', '.', $a));
  $acc = $parts[0];

  $parts = explode('.',str_replace('929292', '.', $b));
  $bcc = $parts[0];

  if($acc == $bcc) { return 0; }
  if($acc > $bcc) { return 1; }
  if($acc < $bcc) { return -1; }
});

var_dump($options);
```

**Edit:** str_replace is kind of pointless here, you could just run explode directly on the key using "929292" as your delimeter.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this could be an exact answer to my own question as it handles the issue but in a different way. Essentially, I've changed my SQL to this:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `ebay_mml`
        WHERE `UKM_CCM` IN ('. $where .')
        AND `UKM_Make` = :make 
        ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTR(`UKM_CCM`, INSTR(`UKM_CCM`, " ") + 1) AS UNSIGNED),
                 `UKM_Model`,
                 `UKM_StreetName`,
                 `Year`
        ASC;';
```

`$where` is a variable generated from a foreach loop:

```
foreach ($cc as $k => $v)
{
    $where .= ':'. $k .($k != end(array_keys($cc)) ? ', ' : '');

    $whereData[':'. $k] = $v;
}
```

This returns all my data at once, so all I need to do now is loop through the results and count the iterations as I go to build the key:

```
$i = 0;

foreach ($data as $result)
{
    # my sexy code
    $i++;
}
```

Now my results are as I want them.

Disclaimer: As this does resolve the issue at hand, it kinda veers away from the original question posed as it's more of a MySQL solution as opposed to sorting/grouping the array by it's key value. Let me know if this answer is ok (if so, will remove the disclaimer segment) or not.

Thanks for your help all :)

Comment: The most important thing is what will future users finding this question need solved? Reading the question over again just now I'd say it's a PHP array sorting issue, so the answer should reflect that. While your answer is of course correct to your situation it uses information not found in the question to solve it so is unlikely to be helpful to future users.

Comment: What you could do is start a new question, rephrased to better match the problem your answer solves and solve it in there.

Comment: @AlexanderDeSousa yeah that's why I'm thinking it may not be an exact answer to the original question :S hm, I'll leave up for now and review it again soon :)